# Where is my Avro-C installed?

Tags: c, makefile

I need Avro C as a prerequisite for further development.I have downloaded it,and installation process in build folder works fine.

```
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/value.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/generic.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/consumer.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/legacy.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/schema.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/refcount.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/errors.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/data.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/platform.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/basics.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/resolver.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/io.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/msinttypes.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/allocation.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include/avro/msstdint.h
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/lib/libavro.a
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/lib/libavro.so.23.0.0
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/lib/libavro.so
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/lib/pkgconfig/avro-c.pc
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/bin/avrocat
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/bin/avroappend
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/bin/avropipe
-- Up-to-date: /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/bin/avromod
```

This is the makefile env. variables part

```
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build
```

Where is my Avro-C installed?There is no bin directory in build folder.I can not find anything in /usr/local.

Comment: It seems to be a *library*. That means you have to add the path to the header files (`/home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/include`) when compiling, and the path to the linker library (`/home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2/build/avrolib/lib`) when linking, as well as linking with the actual `avro` library. There are many tutorials on how to add those both for makefiles and other build-systems, if you just search a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build, (it seems you've done this successfully)

```
cd /home/milenko/avro-c-1.8.2
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
make
```

And then to install the library to your system

```
sudo make install
```

Or just follow the advice in the comment of @Some programmer dude,  and link directly to your build directory.